# Compile JAVA via javac with classpath

Tags: java, javac

I have the following folder structure:

My workspace is /java and the "project" is like this:

```
- de
  - vfh
    - gp1
      - bib
        - Console.class
        - Console.java
      - app
        - MyFile.java
        - MyFile.class
```

So when I do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/java
javac -classpath "." de/vfh/gp1/app/MyFile.java
cd ~/Desktop/java/de/vfg/app/
java MyFile
```

The javac command works well but the java command fails and I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/vfh/gp1/bib/Console
```

Any ideas how my classpath should look like?

Comment: What is the package arrangement?  You need to compile and run at the root of the package structure for "." To work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should run it from the root of your project, and use the full name (with package) of the class:

```
cd ~/Desktop/java/
java de.vfg.app.MyFile
```

BTW - I don't see you compile `Console`, this is obviously needed

Comment: @user3205343 Note the dots instead of slashes in the fully qualified class name.

Comment: @Nir you don't really need to compile Console explicitly; if MyFile references Console, and Console.class doesn't exist, javac will automatically compile Console.java.